# TYPO3: Select count(*) where the hidden rows are included

Tags: sql, select, typo3, typoscript

Im using this code to show the number of registers I have in tt_address in Page ID 68, and works fine, except that it doesnt show the hidden elements.

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page{
  20 = CONTENT
  20 {
    table = tt_address

    select{
      selectFields = count(uid) AS count
      pidInList = 68
      where = deleted = 0
    }

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
      10 = TEXT
      10 {
        value = Status: {field:count}
        insertData = 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How could I count also the hidden records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bypass the "enable fields" where clauses in a normal way, but TYPO3 allows to hack around that using a `UNION` query:

```
select {
    selectFields = count(uid) AS count
    pidInList = 68
    where.data = TSFE:id
    # we hack our way around the enablefields restriction
    where.wrap = 0 UNION SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM tt_address WHERE pid = 68
}
```

Comment: This didnt work :( http://pastebin.com/nWf952Re Could it be that you are missing a "|" in the wrap?

Comment: What's the exact error you get? What SQL is sent to the server? I guess it's broken somehow, but without seeing the SQL statement, I can't say any more.

Comment: It returns 0 rows. The SQL statement that is sent, you can see it in the code I pasted you. I didnt alter it at all.

Comment: I mean the *full* SQL statement that is sent to the server, not the typoscript.

Comment: i want to make a "SELECT count(uid) FROM tt_address WHERE pid = 68 and deleted = 0"

Comment: That was not my question. I you to show me the complete final SQL query that is sent to the MySQL server to fetch the addresses.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24108/discussion-between-dbugger-and-cweiske)

Comment: AFAIK one cannot use .wrap with select.where according to TSREF, one must use andWhere instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to get hidden records using typoscript (no records from hidden, timed or access-protected pages can be  selected!).
Reference link: http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/select

You may need to use "userfunc" as given below:

Typoscript:

```
includeLibs.showHiddenElements = fileadmin/lib/showHiddenElements.php
page.20  =USER
page.20  {
 userFunc =user_showHiddenElements->main
 field = uid
 table = tt_address
 where = deleted = 0 and pid = 68
}
```

fileadmin/lib/showHiddenElements.php :

```
<?php
class user_ShowHiddenElements {
 function main($content, $conf){
    $res=  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTcountRows(
                $conf[field],         // SELECT ...
                $conf[table],     // FROM ...
                $conf[where],    // WHERE...
               '',            // GROUP BY...
               '',    // ORDER BY...
               ''            // LIMIT ...
            );
    return $res;
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
page{
24 = CONTENT
24.wrap = <div class="status_count">|</div>
24 {
    table = tt_address
    select {
        selectFields = count(uid) AS count
        pidInList = 68
        where.data = TSFE:id
        # we hack our way around the enablefields restriction
        where.wrap = |0 UNION SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM tt_address WHERE pid = 68
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.wrap = |</div><div style="display:none">
        10 {
            value = Status: {field:count}
            insertData = 1
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks cweiske for giving me this idea.

Comment: This solution doesnt work. I get 2 times the renderObj. One without the hidden records, and another one with all the records, not only the ones in pid=68

Comment: I also got renderObj twice and that's the reason why I hide one of them with css. Here it's working fine for me.
Did you try my 1st solution using "userfunc"?

Comment: Not yet. Id rather find a solution without userFuncs, and just pure TypoScript, but if nothing comes up, I will accept you other solution

Comment: Ok fine. Please make sure that we have pid = 68 in the above typoscript (where.wrap = |0 UNION SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM tt_address WHERE pid = 68) because I can't find the reason why we are getting all records.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way: e.g. Showing deleted or hidden pages only

```
table = pages
select.pidInList = 1
select.where = deleted=1 or hidden=1 UNION SELECT * FROM pages WHERE 1=0
```

This works 'cause the enablefields are appended to the query. Union with 1=0 where clause returns nothing with the enablefields.